# How to change the PHPExcel Chart x-axis title font Size and color?

Tags: php, phpexcel

My Code is given below:

```
$xAxisTickValuesVS = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', '\''.$wsname.'\'!$H$3:$H$'.($intwstartrow+count($arrscalevs)-1), NULL, count($arrscalevs))    //  Vehicle Speed
);

$dataSeriesValuesVS = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', '\''.$wsname.'\'!$K$3:$K$'.($intwstartrow+count($arrscalevs)-1), NULL, count($arrscalevs))                        
);

$seriesVS = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,       // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,   // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValuesVS)-1),         // plotOrder
    NULL,
    $xAxisTickValuesVS,                             // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValuesVS                             // plotValues
);

$seriesVS->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
$layoutVS = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layoutVS->setShowVal(TRUE);      // Initializing the data labels with Values
$layoutVS->setShowPercent(TRUE);  // Initializing the data labels with Percentages
$plotAreaVS = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layoutVS, array($seriesVS));                 
$titleVS = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Vehicle Speed Utilization');
$xAxisLabelVS = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Speed (Kmph)');                       
$yAxisLabelVS = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('(%) Utlization');

$chartVS = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chartVS',      // name
    $titleVS,           // title
    NULL,       // legend
    $plotAreaVS,        // plotArea
    true,           // plotVisibleOnly
    0,              // displayBlanksAs
    $xAxisLabelVS,          // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabelVS       // yAxisLabel
);

$chartVS->setTopLeftPosition('M3');
$chartVS->setBottomRightPosition('V17');

$objWorksheet->addChart($chartVS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that at the moment.

There's [pull request](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/688) to apply that feature that's 2 years old (you can have a look at the proposed implementation [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/688/files)).

Comment: Currently applying a title shows it with the same font size as that of the Chart Title as both are using the same chart title class. It looks oversized for   xaxis title and with Legends it looks a bit odd.